# Salesforce Create Buttons and Links option - Custom URL to launch email template

Tags: url, salesforce, email-templates

I have an email template that I would like to launch from within the case using a Link/Button. I see the option under setup->customize->cases->button and links I even see where I need to place the URL. What I don't see is nay documentation on how to build the URL to launch an email template. Any help you be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is documented anywhere by salesforce, but I found from some guess work:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00X40000000weWn
```

Just use that as the url content of a custom button or link. This one is for cases, as you are trying to do, but I think this should work for other types of objects as well.

The parameters are `p3_lkid`, which is the case id, `p2_lkid` which is the id of the contact you are emailing, and `template_id` which is hardcoded to the desired email template. (You can find this id by looking in the url of the Setup page for the template)

Comment: And as a general heuristic, try appending `id`, `someobjectId`, or `someobject_id` parameters to a page's url, as you can often tweak salesforce's default behavior with these. There are lots of less obvious ones too (`p3_lkid`??), which you can sometimes find by just clicking onto the destination page from various links and contexts and observing how the url changes.

Comment: Thanks will have to play with this

Answer (score 2):

This was really helpful. I did, however, figure out another way to do it. Click on the "Send an Email" button you currently have. Copy the URL and add `&template_id=YOUR TEMPLATE ID`.

There is one other ID number that will show up in the original URL. Change that to be the dynamic field you want it to be.

For example:

Copy url from "Send Email": https://na3.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=70150000000Axj1&retURL=%2F70150000000Axj1

Add `&template_id=YOUR TEMPLATE ID` so it looks like this:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=70150000000Axj1&retURL=%2F70150000000Axj1&template_id=YOUR TEMPLATE ID
```

Remove the other id (it's the object you used to send the email - so in this case, I was wanting to be able to send an email directly from a Campaign) and replace with the dynamic field:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Campaign.Id}&retURL=%2F70150000000Axih&template_id=YOUR TEMPLATE ID
```

And voila! It should work!

Answer (score 0):

Abeyer's answer is good. However, if the template contains solution attachments "{!Case.Solution_Attachments}" the attachments will not get included unless you add the new_template=1 parameter to the URL making it:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00X40000000weWn&new_template=1
```